# Command completion with full path expansion injected into history for vim

Tags: bash, readline, bash-completion

I've spent a solid week searching online and trying many different ways to solve a tricky problem. Basically, I would like to use vim to edit custom commands / scripts that are in my $PATH without having to actually cd to their given directories first or manually type their **full paths** on the command line.

In essence, I'd love to be able to combine stock bash command completion (compgen -c) with simultaneous path expansion when **specifying scripts in my $PATH as vim FILE ARGUMENTS**. By the way, I'm using the caps to make clear what can be a tricky subject and not shouting.

It's probably easier to show you what I'm trying to do then explain it. Let's say I have scripts in directories that are on my $PATH

```
~/bin/x/y/cmd1.sh
~/bin/a/b/cmd2.sh
/ppp/n/m/cmd3.sh
```

Sometimes these scripts provide functionality on files that exist in other directories so I'd like to be able to edit them *easily* from anywhere in the file system. Sometimes I just want to be able to edit those scripts from other directories because it's more convenient. Let's say I'm currently in the following directory.

```
/completely/different/dir
```

But now I need to vim edit

```
~/bin/a/b/cmd2.sh
```

My options to achieve this solely with default bash functionality is to do one of the following which takes a long time

```
cd ~/bin/a/b/; vim cmd.sh
vim ~/<tab-complete-my-way-to-file>
open a new terminal window plus some combination of the above
```

Since I know the names of my custom scripts it would be soooo much easier to just do the following which requires no tab completion of the full path to the file or directory as well as no cd'ing to a different directory to change my context!

```
vim cmd2.sh
```

But this won't work by default because **vim needs the full path to the script**

My first thought was to write a vim wrapper function which basically uses `which` to do the $PATH expansion for me and then tie bash command completion to my vc function like this:

```
vc () { vim $(which "$@"); }
complete -c vc
```

I can run the following in the shell to complete partial script names that start with "c" from the choices of `cmd1.sh, cmd2.sh, cmd3.sh`

```
vc c<tab>
```

Until I get what I want here which is great

```
vc cmd2.sh
```

When I hit enter and execute the command it all works fine BUT it doesn't inject the expanded path into the READLINE command line and thus **the FULL EXAPANDED PATH of 'cmd2.sh' never winds up in my command history**! My history will show this

```
vc cmd2.sh
```

Instead of

```
vc ~/bin/a/b/cmd2.sh
```

or
vim ~/bin/a/b/cmd2.sh

I want that expanded path in my command history because it makes future operations on that script file super easy when reusing command history. I.e. I can ls, file, diff, mv, cp that expanded path much easier reusing history than writing more wrapper scripts for ls, file, diff, mv, cp etc. Like I had to do with vc above.

Questions:

OPTION 1

Is there a way to reinject the **full expanded path provided by `which`** in my vc function directly back into the original vc READLINE or just inject the entire "vim " command that actually gets executed in vc as a replacement for the original vc command into READLINE? Any method that allows me to get the expanded vim command into the history even if it is in addition to the original vc command is OK by me.

Basically how do you access and edit the current READLINE programmatically in bash?

OPTION 2

Note I can also do something like this DIRECTLY on the command line in real-time

```
vim $(which cmd2.sh) C-x-e
```

Which gives me what I want (it expands the path which will then put it into history) but I have to always type the extra subshell and which text as well as the C-x-e (to expand the line) on every iteration of the command while losing the command completion functionality which basically makes this useless. Put another way, is there anyway to automate the above using a bind key so that

```
vc cmd2.sh
```

Is automatically transformed first into

```
vim $(which cmd2.sh)
```

And then automatically follows up with `C-x-e` so that it gets expanded to

```
vim ~/bin/a/b/cmd2.sh
```

But have all the editing movement, text insertion, and final command line expansion happened all in the same bindkey macro? This might be the best solution of all.

OPTION 3

Alternatively, since bash command completion automatically winds up in the READLINE and thus the history, a custom completion function would solve my problem. is there a way to make vc use a completion function that would **BOTH complete commands in $PATH when used as vim arguments as described above** *AND ALSO SIMULTANEOUSLY EXPAND THEM TO THEIR FULL PATHS?*

I know how to write a basic completion function. Countless hours of attempts (which I am choosing not to put here to keep confusion/post length down) are failing for the simple reason that I'm not sure command completion is compatible with simultaneous full path expansion because it breaks traditional completion.

With a custom completion function, here's what happens when I try to find one of my scripts "cmd2.sh" living in "vim ~/bin/a/b/cmd2.sh" but start with a "c" and hit "".

```
vim c<tab>
```

Instead of getting me these completions to choose from

cmd1.sh
cmd2.sh
cmd3.sh

It completes the first one it finds in the $PATH and inserts it into the READLINE which might be

```
/ppp/n/m/cmd3.sh
```

When I really want

```
~/bin/a/b/cmd2.sh
```

This effectively kills the completion lookup because the word before my cursor in the READLINE now starts with /ppp/n/m/cmd3.sh and there's no way of getting back to cmd2.sh

Comment: Interesting problem. I personally would be content with the `vc` alias, and maybe add another alias to `cd` into the directory and then edit the file there. You then have two aliases, one for just editing, and another one for editing and doing additional operations on the file (now locally). Downside is that you need to know beforehand what you'll intend to do, but this saves you from overloading all other commands in the same way.

Comment: A *really* different take is that if you find yourself needing to frequently edit scripts in `PATH` directories, they aren't sufficiently general. What you need is to make the scripts more useful, not easier to edit.

Comment: @chepner i get what you're saying and in some respects you're right.  the thing is that 1) *while* one is developing those more useful and general scripts that you talk about, what i'm asking for in this post is still really useful and practical to help you get there. 2) i write a lot of scripts and some of them have short lives so the time invested in making them more general and useful isn't worth the extra investment... which is to say, what i want to do has real value and is just another way of solving a problem :)

Comment: @IngoKarkat  i could do that but i'd be setting up more aliases and functions with acronyms amidst too many other alias acronyms i can't remember  so i never use half of them anyway ;)  ie it's just another level of indirection which keeps me from the simplicity of having this automated so it can be reusable in many cases with just one function.  thx for the suggestion!

Comment: A little piece of advice, I think the best way to become good at writing completion functions is to look at how others do it.  Say I want to complete hostnames, I'll do `ssh <TAB><TAB>` once because completion for standard commands are loaded as needed, `complete -p ssh` to find out that the completion function is `_ssh` and with my `vc` (see my answer), `vc _ssh`.   I learned a ton of cool techniques from the completions for `git`, `tmux` `make`, `cmake`, `ssh` a good number of which are applicable outside of writing completion functions.

Answer (score 1):

This requires some boilerplate in your `.bashrc` file, but might work for you. It makes use of the directory stack (some might say it *abuses* the directory stack, but if you aren't using it for anything else, it might be OK).

In your `.bashrc`, add each directory of interest to your directory stack. End the list with your home directory, as `pushd` also changes your current working directory.

```
pushd ~/bin/x/y/cmd1.sh
pushd ~/bin/a/b/cmd2.sh
pushd /ppp/n/m/cmd3.sh
pushd ~
```

Yes, it duplicates your `PATH` entry a bit, but I contend you don't really need access to *every* directory in your `PATH`, just the ones where you have files you intend to edit. (Are you really going to try to edit anything in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`?)

Now, in your interactive shell, you can run `dirs -v` to see, along with its index, the directories in your stack:

```
$ dirs -v
0 ~
1 /ppp/n/m
2 ~/bin/a/b
3 ~/bin/x/y
4 ~
```

Now, no matter where you are, if you want to edit `~/bin/x/y/cmd1.sh`, you can use

```
$ vi ~3/cmd3.sh
```

As long as you don't use `popd` or `pushd` elsewhere to modify the stack, the indices will stay the same. (Using `pushd` will add a new directory to the top of the stack, increasing each index; `popd` will decrease each index after it removes the top directory.)

---

A much simpler process would be to simply define some variables whose values are the desired directories:

```
binab=~/bin/a/b
binxy=~/bin/x/y
ppp=/ppp/n/m
```

and simply expand them

```
$ vi $ppp/cmd3.sh
```

The shell performs parameter name completion, so the variable names don't have to be particularly short, but the dirstack approach guarantees you only need 2 or 3 characters. (Also, it doesn't pollute the global namespace with additional varibles.)

Comment: thanks for the tip @chepner.  the variables don't get expanded and put into history like i want but the paths with vars do allow for reuse from history so it's a workaround.  i still want to know if my original solutions can be worked to inject back into READLINE or via a completion function though.  that would be most seamless.  personally i could probably just rig up fzf to complete my paths and be done with this but again, it's not a native solution with stock bash readline / complete.  thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, I've found myself wanting to do something similar a while back. I hacked together the following bash script. It's pretty self-explanatory. If I want to edit one of my scripts (this one, for example is `~/bin/vm`), I just run `vm vm`. I can open several files in my path, either in buffers, or vertical/horizontal splits etc...

Do with it what you like, pasting it here because it's all ready to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

Usage() {
    cat <<-__EOF_
${0##*/} Opens scripts in PATH from any location (vim -O)
    Example: ${0##*/} ${0##*/}
                opens this script in vim editor
    -o: Change default behaviour (vim -O) to -o
    -b: Change default behaviour to open in buffers (vim file1 file2)
    -h: Display this message
__EOF_
}

flag="O"

vimopen() {
    local wrapped
    local located
    local found
    found=false
    [ $# -lt 1 ] && echo "No script given" && return
    wrapped=""
    for arg in "$@"; do
        if located=$(which "${arg}" 2> /dev/null); then
            found=true
            wrapped="${wrapped} ${located}"
        else
            echo "${arg} not found!"
        fi
    done
    $found || return
    # We WANT word splitting to occur here
    # shellcheck disable=SC2086
    case ${flag} in
        O)
            vim $wrapped -O
            ;;
        o)
            vim $wrapped -o
            ;;
        *)
            vim $wrapped
    esac
}

while getopts :boh f; do
    case $f in
        h)
            Usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        o)
            flag="o"
            shift
            ;;
        b)
            flag=""
            shift
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown option ${f}-${OPTARG}"
            Usage
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
vimopen "$@"
```

Comment: You might want to use an array for your arguments: `local wrapped=()`, in your for loop, `if ... ; then wraped+=("${located}")`.  You can check whether you found anything with `if [[ ${#wrapped[@]} == 0 ]] ; then return` and run vim with `vim "${wrapped[@]}"`.  Note: with a quoted array, word splitting still happens but on the array elements but not on any whitespace within an element.  And you could remove the shellcheck disable thing.

Answer (score 1):

Let me share something that answers OPTION3 part of your answer:

### Behavior of this solution

The solutions that I will show will offer up basenames of commands (i.e. what `compgen -c ${cur}` returns where `cur` is last word on the command line) *until* there is only one candidate in which case it will be replaced by the full path of the command.

```
 $ vc c<TAB><TAB>
Display all 216 possibilities? (y or n)
 $ vc cm<TAB>
cmake       cmake-gui   cmcprompt   cmd1.sh     cmd2.sh     cmd3.sh     cmp         cmpdylib    cmuwmtopbm
 $ vc cmd<TAB>
cmd1.sh  cmd2.sh  cmd3.sh
 $ vc cmd1<TAB>
 $ vc /Users/pcarphin/vc/bin/cmd1.sh
```

which I think is what you want.

And for your `vc` function, you can still do

```bash
vc(){
    vim "$(which "${1}")
}
```

since `which /Users/pcarphin/vc/bin/cmd3.sh` returns `/Users/pcarphin/vc/bin/cmd3.sh` and so it will work whether you do `vc cmd3.sh<ENTER>` or if you do `vc cmd3.sh<TAB><ENTER>`

### Basic solution

So here it is, it's as simple as using `compgen -c` to get command basename candidates and checking if you only have a single candidate and if so, replacing it with the full path.

```
_vc(){

    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return;

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -c ${cur}) )

    #
    # If there is only one candidate for completion, replace it with the
    # full path returned by which.
    #
    if ((${#COMPREPLY[@]} == 1)) ; then
        COMPREPLY[0]=$(which ${COMPREPLY[0]})
    fi
}
complete -F _vc vc
```

### Solution that filters out shell functions

The `compgen -c` command will include the names of shell functions and if you want to leave those out (maybe because your `vc` function would fail which would be inelegant for an argument supplied by a completion function), here is what you can do:

```
_vc(){

    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return;

    local candidates=($(compgen -c ${cur}))

    #
    # Put in COMPREPLY only the command names that are files in PATH
    # and leave out shell functions
    #
    local i=0
    for cmd in "${candidates[@]}" ; do
        if which $cmd 2>/dev/null ; then
            COMPREPLY[i++]=${cmd}
        fi
    done

    #
    # If there is only one candidate for completion, replace it with the
    # full path returned by which.
    #
    if ((${#COMPREPLY[@]} == 1)) ; then
        COMPREPLY[0]=$(which ${COMPREPLY[0]})
    fi
}
```

### Solution that handles shell functions

If we want to handle shell functions, then we can get rid of the part that filters them out and enhance the part that replaces the command name by a full path when `COMPREPLY` contains only one candidate.  This is based on turning on `extdebug` which causes `declare -F shell_function` to output the file where `shell_function` was defined:

```
cmd_location(){
    local location
    if location=$(which "${1}" 2>/dev/null) ; then
        echo "${location}"
    else
        # If extdebug is off, remember that and turn it on
        local user_has_extdebug
        if ! shopt extdebug ; then
            user_has_extdebug=no
            shopt -s extdebug
        fi

        info=$(declare -F ${COMPREPLY[0]})
        if [[ -n "${info}" ]] ; then
            echo ${info} | cut -d ' ' -f 3
        fi
            
        # Turn extdebug back off if it was off before
        if [[ "${user_has_extdebug}" == no ]] ; then
            shopt -u extdebug
        fi
    fi
}

_vc(){

    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return;

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -c ${cur}) )

    if ((${#COMPREPLY[@]} == 1)) ; then
        COMPREPLY[0]=$(cmd_location ${COMPREPLY[0]})
    fi
}
```

And in this case, your `vc` function would need the same kind of logic or you could just remember to always use the shell completion to end up calling it with a full path.

That's why I factored out the `cmd_location` function

```
vc(){
    if [[ "${1}" == /* ]] ; then
        vim "${1}"
    else
        vim $(cmd_location "${1}")
    fi
}
```

I was looking for something else but I found this question which inspired me to do this for myself so thank you, now I'll have a neat `vc` function with a cool completion function.  Personally, I'm going to use the last version which handles shell functions.

The `declare -F` command with `extdebug` prints out the function name, the line number, and the file, so I'll see if I can adapt the solution so that in the case of shell functions, it opens the file at the location.

For that, I'd have to get rid of the part that puts a full path on the command line.  So what I'm going to do for myself won't be an answer to your question.  Note the use of parentheses for `open_shell_function` which makes it run in a subshell so I don't have to do the whole thing with `user_has_extdebug`.

```
open_shell_function()(
    # Use subshell so as not to turn on extdebug in the user's shell
    # and avoid doing this remembering stuff
    shopt -s extdebug

    local info=$(declare -F ${1})
    if [[ -z "${info}" ]] ; then
        echo "No info from 'declare -F' for '${1}'"
        return 1
    fi

    local lineno
    if ! lineno=$(echo ${info} | cut -d ' ' -f 2) ; then
        echo "Error getting line number from info '${info}' on '${1}'"
        return 1
    fi

    local file
    if ! file=$(echo ${info} | cut -d ' ' -f 3) ; then
        echo "Error getting filename from info '${info}' on '${1}'"
        return 1
    fi

    vim ${file} +${lineno}
)

vc(){
    local file
    if file=$(which ${1} 2>/dev/null) ; then
        vim ${file}
    else
        echo "no '${1}' found in path, looking for shell function"
        open_shell_function "${1}"
    fi
}
complete -c vc
```

### Repo link

Since writing the original version of this script, I've found it to be super useful and I've made several improvements to it.  Those who are interested can either clone the repo or download the file by going on the 3rd link and doing 'Save As' in their browser or passing the 3rd link to the `wget` shell command.  In any case, you would then source the file from your .bashrc.

- Repo: https://github.com/PhilippeCarphin/utils
- File in repo: https://github.com/PhilippeCarphin/utils/blob/master/etc/profile.d/vc.bash

This is my personal utilities, it's where I put everything that's too small to be its own repo so not everything will be relevant to non-me people but this one `vc.bash` file should be.

Comment: Where are all these functions put? In `.bashrc` or somewhere else?

Comment: The simplest thing you can do is to put them in some file and source that file in your `.bashrc`.  You could also clone my repo and source `<clone-location>/etc/profile.d/vc.bash` in your `.bashrc`.  I use that `vc` function quite and I have made some improvements to it.  That way you will be able to get any further improvements I make by fetching from my repo.  If you're not used to git though, you can navigate to the file in the github page and click on the "raw" button.  You could then do 'Save As' in your browser.